# How can get a list of all scheduled cron jobs on my machine?

Tags: linux, cron, scheduling

My sysadmin has set up a bunch of cron jobs on my machine. I'd like to know exactly what is scheduled for what time. How can I get that list?

Comment: This isn't the answer to the question, but just a note on best practices. One _can_ configure these as per-user cron jobs for `root` or `apache` or whatever, but one _should_ use `/etc/crontab` or (better, in most distros) `/etc/cron.d` and `/etc/cron.[timeframe]`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134906/how-do-i-list-all-cron-jobs-for-all-users

Comment: I have posted a script which automates this to a useful degree at: - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134906/how-do-i-list-all-cron-jobs-for-all-users/53892185#53892185 It's not perfect but probably covers 90% of the needs. It is a good example of what not to write in bash.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Depending on how your linux system is set up, you can look in:

- `/var/spool/cron/*` (user crontabs)
- `/etc/crontab` (system-wide crontab)

also, many distros have:

- `/etc/cron.d/*`
  These configurations have the same syntax as `/etc/crontab`
- `/etc/cron.hourly`, `/etc/cron.daily`, `/etc/cron.weekly`, `/etc/cron.monthly`

These are simply directories that contain executables that are executed hourly, daily, weekly or monthly, per their directory name.

On top of that, you can have at jobs (check `/var/spool/at/*`), anacron (`/etc/anacrontab` and `/var/spool/anacron/*`) and probably others I'm forgetting.

Comment: Thanks, I found them in `/etc/cron.daily`. How does that `daily` file work? What time will the daily jobs run? On my machine they seem to run around noon, but it'd like to tell my sysadmin how to change that to midnight instead.

Comment: cron.daily is called from `/etc/crontab`, e.g. on my Ubuntu system it's: `25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )` which means 6:25 am.

Comment: cron.daily is called from /etc/crontab on my RHEL5 system too, if you'd like more data points.

Comment: On newer Fedora (and probably RHEL6 -- haven't looked yet), the `cronie` daemon takes care of those using the configuration in `/etc/anacrontab`.

Comment: Sometimes it's in `/var/cron` too.

Comment: I'm using `at`jobs but `/var/spool/at/*` does not exists.

Comment: I don't think you're forgetting any. A very complete listing. Thanks!

Answer (score 175):

With most Crons (e.g. [Vixie-Cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Modern_versions) - Debian/Ubuntu default, Cronie - Fedora default, Solaris Cron ...) you get the list of scheduled cron jobs for the current user via:

```
$ crontab -l
```

or for another user via

```
# crontab -l -u juser
```

To get the crontabs for all users you can loop over all users and call this command.

Alternatively, you can look up the spool files. Usually, they are are saved under `/var/spool/cron`, e.g. for vcron following directory

```
/var/spool/cron/crontabs
```

contains all the configured crontabs of all users - except the root user who is also able to configure jobs via the system-wide crontab, which is located at

```
/etc/crontab
```

With [cronie](https://fedorahosted.org/cronie) (default on Fedora/CentOS), there is a `.d` style config directory for system cron jobs, as well:

```
/etc/cron.d
```

(As always, the `.d` directory simplifies maintaining configuration entries that are part of different packages.)

For convenience, most distributions also provide a directories where linked/stored scripts are periodically executed, e.g.:

```
/etc/cron.daily
/etc/cron.hourly
/etc/cron.monthly
/etc/cron.weekly
```

The timely execution of those scripts is usually managed via `run-parts` entries in the system crontab or via [anacron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anacron).

With [Systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) (e.g. on Fedora, CentOS 7, ...) periodic job execution can additionally be configured via [timer units](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html). The enabled system timers can be displayed via:

```
$ systemctl list-timers
```

Note that users beside root may have user systemd instances running where timers are configured, as well. For example, on Fedora, by default, a user systemd instance is started for each user that is currently logged in. They can be recognized via:

```
$ ps aux | grep 'systemd[ ]--user'
```

Those user timers can be listed via:

```
$ systemctl --user list-timers
```

An alternative to issuing the `list-timers` command is to search for timer unit files (pattern: `*.timer`) and symbolic links to them in the usual system and user systemd config directories:

```
$ find /usr/lib/systemd/ /etc/systemd -name '*.timer'
$ find /home '(' -path '/home/*/.local/share/systemd/user/*' \
              -o -path '/home/*/.config/systemd/*' ')' \
      -name '*.timer'  2> /dev/null
```

(As with normal service units, a timer unit is enabled via creating a symbolic link in the right systemd config directory.)

See also:

- [ArchWiki article on Cron](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/cron)
- [ArchWiki article on Systemd Timers](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers)

Comment: I didn't downvote. But I just tried `crontab -l -u root` (because those cronjobs I want to know about run under `root`), and it says I don't have privileges to use `-u`.

Comment: Then you have to call it with enough privileges - i.e. as `root` user.

Comment: Still not complete — some versions of cron run jobs from /etc/cron.d and /etc/cron.{daily,hourly,monthly,weekly} without a helper program called from /etc/crontab.

Comment: @mattdm, sure  - thus the first sentence 'Probably depends on the crond you are using' - but looking at /etc/crontab you usually see references of /etc/cron.d, /etc/cron.daily etc.

Comment: @maxschlepzig - but not always. And the question is "how can I get a list of _all_ cron jobs"; an reply which is "well, here's some of them" isn't the answer.

Comment: @mattdm, which crond has a `/etc/crontab` that does not include references to `/etc/cron.daily` etc. and does support `/etc/cron.daily` and friends via other builtin mechanisms?

Comment: @maxschlepzig — `cronie`, as shipped in Fedora and RHEL6, do not refer to those in `/etc/crontab`, but instead use `/etc/anacrontab`. I may be mistaken about any actual implementations that don't refer to these in any config file. (But then, I didn't downvote either.... I'm just sayin'.)

Comment: @mattdm, fair enough

Answer (score 9):

To list all crons for the given user.

> crontab -u username -l;

To list all crons for all users

Run it as a super user

```
#!/bin/bash
#List all cron jobs for all users
for user in `cat /etc/passwd | cut -d":" -f1`;
do 
crontab -l -u $user;
done
```

Comment: OP is asking for a list of _all_ cron jobs.

Comment: For some reason that doesn't show /etc/cron.d/ jobs.

Comment: It's not working. "no crontab for www-data". but username www-data is exists.

Answer (score 2):

You can list all cron jobs with (I'm using more to list the location in the output):

```
sudo sh -c 'more /etc/crontab /etc/cron.d/* /var/spool/cron/crontabs/* 2>/dev/null' | less
```

Or without comments:

```
sudo sh -c 'more /etc/crontab /etc/cron.d/* /var/spool/cron/crontabs/* 2>/dev/null' \
   | grep "^\s*[^#]"
```

crontab has entries to run the scripts in cron.hourly, daily, weekly and monthly - you can list those with:

```
ls /etc/cron.hourly /etc/cron.daily /etc/cron.weekly /etc/cron.monthly
```

Comment: Nice. In CentOS 7, had to use `/var/spool/cron/*`, plus anacron jobs, e.g. `cron.daily` e.g. combined together becomes `sudo sh -c 'more /etc/crontab /etc/cron.d/* /var/spool/cron/* /etc/cron.*/* 2>/dev/null' | less` `